# Visual Studio 2019 Not Starting

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Today, I installed Visual Studio 2019 V16.3.2.

After finishing the installation successfully, application did not launch. It just shows the opening screen and closes immediately. The same happened when tried to run the app using devenv.exe /SafeMode.

Following error threw after 2 or 3 minutes later.

[image: Error threw when tried open VS 2019]

To find more information about this error, checked the activity log of the Visual Studio at the location (`C:\Users\Muvindu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_cebced82`) and found some errors.

Following is the activity log.

[Visual Studio Activity Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bimBQj4O6bzgD5ego7SOYvSys1oopiL1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you run [VS in safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019#syntax)?

Comment: Judging from similar bug reports, this mishap is caused by a VS component that interfaces to Node.js.  Edit the system environment and remove any variables whose name start with "node".  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/287499/systeminvalidoperationexception-controller-termina.html

Comment: @magicandre1981 tried with safe mode too, but didn't work

Comment: @HansPassant couldn't find any variable starting with "node"

Comment: send it as [feedback to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2015?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019). If doesn't start use feedback entry from VS installer

Answer (score 0):

Today, I installed Visual Studio 2019 and I was Facing same issue. Just to Restart My Computer Problem resolved.